# I need to read a text file inside a function and loop the script every 1 second

Tags: javascript, html

I have a local html page that will be used only on my PC (without client / server) and I need to use a bar to indicate how much is missing to reach the maximum number defined, being that I have a txt file for me to put the maximum number and another txt file that a program will increment the number as needed.

I found this script and it already does the part of being able to choose the maximum number, the current one and show the results in the bar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Created using JS Bin
http://jsbin.com

Copyright (c) 2017 by anonymous (http://jsbin.com/tohaqupuge/1/edit)

Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
-->
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="pb"></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button id="recreate" class="k-button">Re-create progressbar</button>
<script id="jsbin-javascript">
$(function(){
    createProgressBar(0, 100, 75);
});

$("#recreate").click(function(){
    $("#pb").data("kendoProgressBar").destroy();
    $("#wrapper").empty().append("<div id='pb'></div>");
    createProgressBar(100, 500, 220);
});

function createProgressBar(min, max, value) {
  $("#pb").kendoProgressBar({
    min: min,
    max: max,
    value: value
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This can be tested online here: http://jsbin.com/sawatobewi/edit?html,js,output

The problem is that in this code I have to manually edit the ***createProgressBar line (0, 100, 75);*** to change the maximum number (in case 100) and the current number (75). And I'm having to refresh the page manually to refresh the bar.

So I need the script to read the contents of the maxnumber.txt file instead of the number 100 and read the contents of the currentnumber.txt file in place of the number 75.

Lastly, I need this script to refresh every 1 second to update the bar without updating the page.

I am not a programmer, I only understand about shell script, so I've tried to adapt several code but nothing worked. I also tried reading the documentation about JavaScript but this is much more complex than shell script, so I really need someone to do these two modifications.

Comment: Where is the code you're using to read the text file?

Comment: as i said: 
"The problem is that in this code I have to manually edit the createProgressBar line (0, 100, 75);"
"So I need the script to read the contents of the maxnumber.txt file instead of the number 100 and read the contents of the currentnumber.txt file in place of the number 75."

So i dont have a code to read the text file, thats why im asking this